# How to unmount a nfs or ntfs when a NAS is not reachable?

Tags: rhel, mount, fstab, nas

I have this environemnt:

Redhatlinux Enterprise

on fstab a NAS mounted as NFS

`yyyy.xxx.com:/vol/yyyy_nec_nosnap12/prod_data on /prod_data type nfs (rw,bg,addr=x.y.z.w)`

when the NAS doesn't reply (due to maintenance or issues) the system degrade and became stuck.

Is there any param to ask linux to umount the NAS when unreachable?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [autofs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/nfs-autofs.html) to mount the NFS share.  When your NFS server isn't reachable, it won't be able to automount the volume.

Comment: I guess OP means that the connection to the NAS stops while the server is already up.

Comment: yes correct, I need to unmount when the NAS i unreachable or the system co in stuck; autonfs is good starting point but I do not know if it the best solution

Comment: Well, you could always force the unmount (`umount -f ...`) when that happens.

Comment: Automatically? I need to dismount when not available

Comment: No, not automatically. That's why you use autofs. 'umount -f' is for force unmounting of a broken hard mount.